# Is it possible to delete cookie when a site is closed?

Tags: php, cookies

Is it possible to delete cache and cookie of a specific site when it is closed.

For example,

**Let us consider I am creating an bank application. Due to security reasons i need to clear the cache and cookie of my site when the user logs out or when the user closes the site..**

How can this be done using PHP?

Comment: 1.I think the cache you mean is client-side cache,this is not under your control,but cookie is 2.PHP can manipulate cookie using setcookie() function 3.close site event is not reliable,I think you could use session-life-cycle cookie,that is-not to specify cookie's expire,so it would destroy it self since the browser close

Comment: Well, start by using the *right kind* of cookie -- an HTTP-only "session cookie" in this case. Then, only use *one* cookie, and make it an expiring nonce (and hopefully backed by a well-tested vs. roll-your-own authentication mechanism). Also make sure only https:// is allowable, and don't store sensitive information in URLs. And ... uhm, buy an existing library/framework? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the code in Client side, not server side, at least to capture the closing of a site from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't clear the cache, but you can prevent things from getting cached in the first place by sending a `cache-control` header with a `no-cache` value with every request:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Deleting cookies can be done only on logout, just overwrite the cookie like you set it but with a blank body.

You should terminate a session after a few minutes of inactivity and when the cookie is still set on the next login or if you haven't logged a logout on the last session (even better) inform the user on his next login that he should logout for security reasons.

**Edit:**
By the way - you don't ever want to cache anything that's in anyway confidential. Even if you COULD tell the browser to delete that stuff you still couldn't tell the browser to overwrite all the information with zero values so the information is still on the disc and could possibly be undeleted...